# Why do ripped music files start with a number? Is there a way to remove in bulk or prevent these from occuring in future CD rips?

Tags: windows, mp3, windows-media-player, ripping

I just ripped 90 CDs to my PC, and each of the music file titles begin with a number like so:

[image]

- Why are these numbers present?
- Is there a way to remove these in bulk?
- Is there a way to prevent these from generating in future CD rips?

Comment: What is your ripper?

Comment: The numbers are the track numbers, and that is normal.

Comment: @harrymc Windows Media Player

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default file name used in Windows Media Player for ripped music is:
*Track-Number Song-Title*.

To modify the format of the file name:

- Select *Rip settings > More options*
- In the Options window position to the "Rip Music" tab
- Click "File Name..."
- Select the options, unchecking at least "Track number"
- You may also change the order of the fields
- Click OK.

[image]

For more information with screenshots see the article
[How to rip a CD with Windows Media Player, in Windows](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-rip-audio-cds-windows-media-player-12/).